# Create a dict based on key-value pairs without using a for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I still have a solution but wonder if there is a more pythonic version with in-built Python tools.

- The goal would be to avoid the for loop.
- Does Python offer a technique (package) to solve this?

I have 2 lists of the same length, one representing keys (with possible duplicates) and the other the values.

```
keys = list('ABAA')
vals = [1, 2, 1, 3]
```

The expected result:

```
{
    'A': [1, 1, 3],
    'B': [2]
}
```

My working solution (with Python 3.9):

```
result = {}

for k, v in zip(keys, vals):
    # create new entry with empty list
    if k not in result:
        result[k] = []

    # store the value
    result[k].append(v)

print(result)
```

Comment: This seems like a job for [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but when you have _working code_ you think could be improved, that's generally more appropriate for [codereview.se]. You can't avoid the loop here, as you want to iterate over all of the pairs of values.

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to your solution (which is great btw), but you could `zip` the lists and use `dict.setdefault`:

```
out = {}
for k,v in zip(keys,vals):
    out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Output:

```
{'A': [1, 1, 3], 'B': [2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use this:

```
keys = list('ABAA')
vals = [1, 2, 1, 3]

d = {}
for key in set(keys):
    d[key] = [vals[i] for i in range(len(keys)) if keys[i] == key]
```

Comment: This isn't an efficient solution; it iterates over the whole list for every key, so is O(n**2).